# How to describe Input Parameter in a RESTful Web Service

Tags: rest

Im developeing a RESTful Service in which Processes can be executed and proivde a resulting calculation. For this i have modeled the process itself as a Resource (Example: /processes/translate). I want to execute the process by sending a GET request with appended Input Parameter as Query Parameter (Example: /processes/translate?input1=xxxx&input2=xxxxx).

Each process has different Input Parameter which are defined during the process creation in the backend. My Question is how should i document or describe which inputs are needed to execute a process in machine readable form. For Example in XML.

Until now ive integrated atom:link elements in the Representation. i thought that maybe including XFORM could be a soluttion?

Best Regards
Andre

Answer (score 2):

I would not model this with a GET.  While it's the easier solution, it's also (IMO) the least RESTful.  I would have clients POST a document describing what they want you to translate and your service sends them back a URI where their answer can be found (some translations might take a while).

Example (ommiting a lot of HTTP headers/context)

```
POST /processes/translate
Content-Type: application/xml
...

<translation-request>
   <input1 type="type1">....</input1>
   <input2 type="type5">....</input2>
</translation-request>
```

Response:

```
200 OK
Content-Location: /processes/translate/jobs/1234
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am also using your recomended way . i want to offer two was of execution, a on the fly execution following the pattern described in Restful Web Services Cookbook (by using GET) and a asynchronious execution of a process, like you described (with POST). Im looking for a best practice how to give a client the information for the input parameter the process needs and how to embed this, for example in a Atom Rrepresenation. 
Sorry for my English!

Comment: Well the agreed format (like an Atom representation) is something that REST says can be done out of band.  It's really close to impossible to send the client something that a machine can interpret and "fill in the blanks" with the correct formats.  Having a wiki/FAQ/whatever that describes the excepted format for a synchronous and asynchronous request just needs to be available to clients.

Answer (score 0):

That's always an interesting question. We have a project called RESTx (http://restx.org), with which you can create [RESTful web services](http://restx.mulesoft.org) very easily. You can write custom component code in either Java or Python and then create [RESTful resources](http://restx.mulesoft.org/about-restful-resources) by sending parameter sets to the server, which are then stored. Each parameter set gets its own URI, though, so you can always just run the code with those parameters by accessing the new parameter set's URI.

Importantly, the entire RESTful API, is automatically created. RESTx examines the component code and then assembles the API description. We decided to describe parameters in a way that is human as well as machine readable. You can see examples of what that looks like [in a browser](http://restx.mulesoft.org/tour-server-web-browser) or [in plain JSON](http://restx.mulesoft.org/restful-server-api).

I'm the lead developer on that, so please feel free to contact me about any questions you might have.